# fullcalendar - EventLimit for agendaWeek

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement an agendaView using fullcalendar api. what I want is: if there is more than 2 events for the same period (today 2pm-3pm = 4 events) it will show 2 events plus "+2 more".

so I used the following code:

```
eventLimit: true,
views: {
        agenda: {
            eventLimit: 2
        },
        week: {
            eventLimit: 2
        },
}
```

it works, but only for allDayEvents... not for events with an end date. 
what I'm getting is [this](http://s22.postimg.org/xn6d6m16p/image.jpg) when I want [this](http://s27.postimg.org/gfaba31mr/image.jpg)

but I simply want to limit my events, does anyone knows why my code isn't working? thanks a million

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/) (emphasis mine):

> For the **all-day section** in the agenda views, a value of true will
>   limit the number of events to 5.

It doesn't support limiting the number of events on the agenda portion of the calendar.

It also isn't very clear how that would even work. It's one thing if all the events are at exactly the same time but how do you group events that look like:

[image: Fullcalendar - lots of overlapping events]